# Systematic way of specifying ARIMA(p,d,q) which surprisingly normalizes residuals

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, normalization

Based on what I read in this (very) helpful/clear/pedagogical article [ARIMA models for time series forecasting](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm), I decided to systemize a way of specifying an ARIMA model.

My algorithm actually computes the PACF of MLE-based residuals, and then (given that my series exhibits an AR signature -- indeed a first nonseasonal difference of my series returns a lag-1 negative autocorrelation lower than -.5, I consequently decided to add AR term to correct for mild under-differencing --), it iteratively identifies the most significant lag, turns it into an AR term, recomputes the PACF, re-identifies the most significant lag, and so on...

To summarize, the algo

1. Starts with (a constant-only model) an empty list of AR terms
2. Computes the PACF using the (empty or growing) list
3. Identifies the most significant lag and adds it to the list of AR terms
4. Goes to step 2

Sometimes, at step 2, the algorithm identifies a lag which is already present in the list. In this case, instead of adding it to the list (which would have no sense -- non full-rank explanatory matrix/perfect colinearity), it takes the (seasonal?) difference associated to the lag, keeping all previous AR terms. And curiously/interestingly, it cleans the residuals, making them normal ! Below a gif in which we are shown the process

[image: my algo]

> iXoY ............. reads X difference(s) using succesively the Yth lag(s)
>
> arW-X-Y-Z .... reads as the list of lags used as AR terms

***In the above gif, (or the capture below) we see that differencing twice at lag 40 and using the lags 1, 2, 4, 7, 15, 40 as AR terms, yield residuals whose null hypothesis of normality is highly conserved*** (I used a shapiro test since it is one of the most powerfull -- even if I cannot find anymore the reference in which I read that.).

The model which is being selected is (whose PACF of the residuals is shown below)

$\Delta^2_{40} y_t = \sum_{l \in \{1,2,4,7,15,40\}} \rho_l \Delta^2_{40} y_{t-l} + \varepsilon_t$

where $\Delta^2_{40}$ stands for two differences made against lag 40.

[image]

***What enormous mistake am I currently doing ?***

Comment: Why would you take a seasonal difference instead of adding a seasonal AR term? Seasonal differencing is only appropriate in presence of a seasonal unit root. And in general, you might be noise mining when including higher-order lags...

Comment: Because I already added the term under question as an AR, did not I ? The 40th I mean.

Comment: I don't really understand what model is being selected in your gif, but I think it could be seasonal differencing that makes lag 40 stick out ever more.

Comment: @RichardHardy. The selected model would be $\Delta^2_{40} y_t = \sum_{l \in \{1,2,4,7,15,40\}} \rho_l \Delta^2_{40} y_{t-l} + \varepsilon_t$ where $\Delta^2_{40}$ stands for two differences made at lag 40.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I suspected. Does not look sensible.

Comment: Step 4 should be "Goes to step 2.", right?